# Python: ping betwen two networks

Tags: python, ping, lan

I'm trying to make a simple python script to ping all devices in my company, but I stuck in pinging between two networks: 192.168.0.x and 192.168.10.x

Is there a way to ping addresses in 192.168.10.x from 192.168.0.x without making changes in LAN configuration?

```
from pythonping import ping

ips = ['192.168.0.88', '192.168.0.253', '192.168.0.182', '192.168.0.9', '192.168.0.1', '192.168.10.10',
       '192.168.10.5']

def check_by_ping(ip=[]):
    ret = []
    for ip in ips:
        p = ping(ip, count=1)
    
        if p.rtt_max_ms == 2000:
            ret.append([ip, False])
            print('Wynik: ', ip, ' = ', 'Nieosiągalne!!!')
        else:
            ret.append([ip, p.rtt_max_ms])
            print('Wynik: ', ip, ' = ', p.rtt_max_ms)
        
    return ret

c = 0

while c<100:  
    print('\n Test nr: ',c,'\n')
    check_by_ping(ips)
    c += 1
```

Comment: "ingerenting" isn't a word, so I'm not clear exactly what you're asking. Can you perhaps rephrase the question?

Comment: sorry for that, i ment "making changes".

Comment: What is the netmask?  Check that it is 255.255.0.0.  If it is 255.255;255;0 it will never work.

Comment: It's 255.255.255.0... thanks for a tip.